# Using XPath to concatenate all child nodes

Tags: xpath

I need an XPath to concatenate all the <ns1:string> texts:

XML:

```
<ns2:texts>  
  <ns1:string>ABCD</ns1:string>  
  <ns1:string>PQRS</ns1:string>  
  <ns1:string>XYZ</ns1:string> 
</ns2:texts>
```

Expected Output:

```
ABCD PQRS XYZ
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

In XPath 1.0,

if `<ns2:texts>` contains only `<ns1:string>` elements, you can use:

`normalize-space(//ns2:texts)`

Output: `ABCD PQRS XYZ`

See http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/e4c7a4daf085c56243b803427e90bdfe

Comment: ah nice idea, I didn't think of that

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 2.0 you can use `string-join()` function, like so :

```
string-join(//ns1:string, ' ')
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/29d3667788478b15074da720e7219d00)</kbd>**

**input :**

```
<ns2:texts xmlns:ns2="foo" xmlns:ns1="bar">  
  <ns1:string>ABCD</ns1:string>  
  <ns1:string>PQRS</ns1:string>  
  <ns1:string>XYZ</ns1:string> 
</ns2:texts>
```

**output :**

```
ABCD PQRS XYZ
```